# Different .HTACCESS for different folders

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a problem when configuring .htaccess for different folders. I have the folder structure mentioned below.

```
root/
|-- resources/
|-- config/
|-- libraries/
|-- admin/
|    |-- resources/
|    |-- config/
|    |-- libraries/
|    |-- index.php
|    |-- .htaccess
|-- index.php
|-- .htaccess
```

I need to configure the htaceess for the root and admin folder. I need the .htaccess from the root to ignore the admin folder, but when the url has admin folder it should use the .htacess file from the admin folder. For example

```
www.domain.com/person/add
www.domain.com/person/edit/1
www.domain.com/person/view/1
```

should use the .htaccess file from the root. When the url has admin folder it should use the .htaccess file from the admin folder. For example

```
www.domain.com/admin/person/add
www.domain.com/admin/person/edit/1
www.domain.com/admin/person/view/1
```

The below is the root .htaccess file that I configured.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(admin)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But it doesn't work for the admin folder. How to configure the .htaccess file for both root and the admin folder.

Comment: `%{REQUEST_URI}` *always* begins with a /, so it would be `%{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin`. Don't have time to check if that is actually the problem here though.

Comment: By default, htaccess files in subdirectories have *precedence* over any htaccess file in parent folders (including root). Are you sure something else isn't going on here?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, you almost had it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```